# Equivalent solutions to Fourier series of $e^x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I wanted to find the Fourier series of $e^x$ on $[-L,L]$.

Using the Complex Form of
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} C_n e^{i \frac{n\pi}{L}x}$$
with 
$$C_n = \frac{1}{2L} \int_{-L}^L f(x) e^{i \frac{n\pi}{L}x} \mathrm{d}x$$
I get
$$C_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{L}\frac{1+i\frac{n\pi}{L}}{1+\frac{n^2\pi^2}{L^2}}\sinh(L)$$
$$\boxed{f(x) = \frac{\sinh{L}}{L}  \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{1+\frac{n^2\pi^2}{L^2}}\left(1+i \frac{n\pi}{L}\right)e^{i \frac{n\pi}{L}}}$$

Using the form of the Real form:

$$f(x) = A_0 + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n \cos(\frac{n\pi}{L}) +B_n \sin(\frac{n\pi}{L})$$

with 
\begin{align}
&A_n = 2 \Re(C_n) = \frac{2(-1)^n}{L+\frac{n^2\pi^2}{L^2}}\sinh{L}\\
&A_0 = \frac{2}{L} \sinh(L)\\
&B_N = -2\Im(C_n)=\frac{2(-1)^{n+1}\frac{n\pi}{L}}{L+\frac{n^2\pi^2}{L^2}}\sinh{L}
\end{align}

I get
$$\boxed{f(x) = \frac{2\sinh(L)}{L}\left[1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{1+\frac{n^2\pi^2}{L^2}}\left(\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)-\frac{n\pi}{L}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)\right)\right]}$$

If my calculations are correct these two representations of the solution are equivalent.

But when I look at the Complex Fourier solution I just dont see how it can be completely real and equivalent to the regular form. I can imagine that through some analysis one can show that the values given by the complex form are purely real.

Can someone give me insight on how to see this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The imaginary part in the complex Fourier series is $0$: If $a_n=-a_{-n}$ then $\sum_{-\infty} ^{\infty} (-1)^{n}a_n=0$. [ Note that $(-1)^{n}=(-1)^{-n}$].

Comment: Sorry, but you could mind elaborating on that? I cant see how substituting $-n$ instead of $n$ into my $C_n$ would give me $C_n=-C_{-n}$. And also is there a more intuitive conceptual explanation to this realization rather than pure algebra ? (sorry if that doesnt make sense).

Comment: Split $(1+i\frac {n\pi} L)e^{i\frac {n\pi} L}$ into its real and imaginary parts; use the fact that $\sin$ is an odd function and $\cos$ is an even function.

Comment: I get that to be $\cos \frac{n\pi}{L} - \frac{n\pi}{L}  \sin \frac{n\pi}{L}  + i( \sin \frac{n\pi}{L}  + \frac{n\pi}{L}  \cos \frac{n\pi}{L})   $, and then I'm not sure where to go from there? Additionally, what happened to manipulating $-C_n$ to show it is equal to $C_{-n}$? Why are we only looking at $(1+i\frac{n\pi}{L} )e^{i\frac{n\pi}{L} }$

Comment: $n^{2}$ does not change when you replace $n$ by $-n$ . In the complex number you have obtained what happens to the imaginary part if you replace $n$ by $-n$?.

Comment: im on my phone now, but from what I can see the imaginary part will now have a negative infront of all of it. So the $C_n$ and $C_{-n}$ terms will have opposite imaginaries and their real parts are the same.. which is why we get $2\Re(C_n)$ as the fourier coefficient in the regular series. I think I understand it now?

Comment: Yes, you seem to have got it.

Comment: thank you for leading me to explore the intuition myself